# How to retrieve an organization's private key?

Tags: chef, private-key

I've just installed Chef Server version 12, and created an admin user and default organization *myorg*.  I see the organization in the Chef Manage GUI, and its public key.  Using a workstation that's running Chef 11, I can connect to the Chef server using the private key *webui_priv.pem* and successfully run commands like *knife user list*.

Now I'm attempting to bootstrap a node, and to do so, I believe I need the organization myorg's *private* key.  However, Chef Manage only shows me its *public* key.

Where do I find the organization's private key?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:  https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_server.html#org-create

When you create the organization with the *chef-server-ctl org-create* command, it allows you to redirect the private key to a file with the *-f* parameter.

If you use the Chef Manage GUI to create the organization, it displays the private key and also allows you to download it, saying that the private key is NOT stored anywhere on the server.